# Access the same Josn field which are inside {} curly brackers under the same column in postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql

I want to query the element `locktype` and the `workspaceID` from within the different curly brackets fields under the **column** named `value`,

For example:

```
[
  {
    "score":0.0,
    "locktype":1,
    "rank":1,
    "workspaceId":"4R5"
  },
  {
    "score":0.0,
    "lockType":2,
    "rank":2,
    "workspaceId":"6yt"
  }
]
```

The result should be like,

| Locktype | workspaceID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4R5 |
| 2 | 6yt |

The **table name** is `Custom`.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sorry, I added `locktype=2` now. I am not sure, why workspaceID for locktype=1 is empty in the question, but I have added a value for it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have updated it now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According [Postgres document](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) You can use `json_array_elements` and cross join.

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=07b5b26ca53789f8a639eec5becf7669)

```sql
select
  ej.value ->> 'locktype' as locktype,
  ej.value ->> 'workspaceId' as workspaceId
from
  test t
  cross join json_array_elements(t.value::json) ej
```